# Prove from the definition that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, where $x_n = 1/ (3^n)$ for all $n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $\epsilon > 0$ is given, we choose a natural number $H = H(\epsilon)$ such that $H > 2/\epsilon$. Then if $m ,n >H$, we have $1/(3^n) < 1/H < \epsilon/2$ and similarly $1/(3^m) < \epsilon/2$. Therefore, it follows that if $m, n > H$, then

$|(1/3^n)-(1/3^m)|<(1/3^n)+(1/3^m)<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$

therefore $1/(3^n)$is cauchy sequence

is this right?

Comment: It seems to be ok. In general any sequence that is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$(or any complete space) is a Cauchy-sequence.

Comment: Any convergent sequence is Cauchy. I think what you mean to say @SamratMukhopadhyay is that a Cauchy sequence in a complete space is also convergent.

Comment: @SimonS so does my proof look right?

Comment: The converse is also true. See [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_is_Cauchy_Sequence) and actually I should say it is true in any metric space, not necessarily complete.